# How can I go on about getting the right output to the user in this recursive function in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
def fibs_rec (n,barray = []) 
  return 1 if n == 1 || n == 0 

  a = fibs_rec(n-1,barray) + fibs_rec(n-2,barray)
  barray << a 
  return a 
end
```

for description, This function takes an argument n and prints the first n numbers in the fibonacci sequence but, it isnt quite working as it is supposed to be.

I want it to print the first n fibonacci numbers without any repetitions. 
for example if n is 4, output should be 0,1,1,2 instead of 0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,2. That basically happens when i print barray inside the recursion because i dont have any other option and for that sake i have removed that line.

The thing is I cant remove the `return a` and replace it with `return barray`. Not only will that mess up the functionality, fibs_rec is expecting to get a number back to perform the calculations and that wont work when I will return `barray` just to display the output to the user and neither can I print array because that will keep outputting the new data alongside with the old data and I just want it to be a one single clean output of the whole fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, you cannot remove `return a` and replace with `return barray` because 
`fibs_rec(n-1, barray) + fibs_rec(n-2, barray)` will return an `array` instead of `integer`.

```
def fibs_rec(n, barray = []) 
  return 1 if n == 1 || n == 0

  a = fibs_rec(n-1, barray) + fibs_rec(n-2, barray) # a = [2] + [2] wrong!
  barray << a
  return barray # return an array[]
end
```

[image: Fibonacci tree of 6]

Moreover, according to your problem description, it would be better not to write in a recursive program but if you are required to do a recursive program, I would suggest you that the `fibs_rec` function you wrote isn't trying to print the pattern but trying to find the fibo number at position `n`. For example:

```
# According to your program, you will miss the first 0 of fibonacci sequence
# (0,) 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, ……..
fibs_rec(0) # return: 1
fibs_rec(1) # return: 1
fibs_rec(2) # return: 2
fibs_rec(3) # return: 3
fibs_rec(4) # return: 5
. . .
```

If you want to print out the sequence using recursive function `fibs_rec`, you will need to create another function to call it from `0` to `n`.

There are a lot of good resources explaining about Fibonacci and recursive out there. You do not quite understand how recursive works. Try to understand it first. Good luck!